# Add Options to {loadedmoduleid ID}

Tags: custom-component, custom-module

I want to create a module that implements animated icons into my articles. For this I want to use the following icon-pack: https://github.com/icons8/titanic

Then I want to somehow write in my article {loadedmodule ID, options}  where options would be something like 'mail','sidebar','preferences' and so on. Based on that I want to change the icon displayed. But when make a var_dump of the $params-Variable in my module this informations doesn't gets passed on.

Do you have any idea on how I could pass data directly from an article to a module?

Comment: Can we see some of your code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best resource I was recommended, by another Joomla book author Tim Plummer, in regards to Joomla Plugins and Joomla development in general is this book from Jisse Reitsma, Programming Joomla! Plugins. I bought a 2nd hand copy from Amazon but I have since found a .pdf version to download somewhere on the net so if you go searching you should be able to find it.

And Jisse has a few video out there from past Joomla events that I also learnt a lot from, not just plugins but some other ways to think about Joomla and cross CMS development.

Terry

Comment: Terry, duplicated answers are flagged for potential moderator destruction.  If two pages are suitably resolved with the same answer, there's a good chance that one of the pages should be closed as a duplicate of the other.  Simply put, Stack Exchange does not wish to house redundant content.  You may like to amend one or both of your posts to specifically suit the respective questions.

Comment: I tried to delete this answer and make it a comment to the question by the OP in Arlen's answer as he/she should get the credit for putting the OP onto using a Plugin, but now I can't because the answer got Accepted. If you can change that it would make more sense to then delete my answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. You sure you need a module for that, and not a plugin?

There's no mechanism in place to pass parameters from an article to a module, cleanly. They all center around the module getting the menu item, then walking that to the article and going from there.

But the plugin mechanism has the ability to pass arguments built right into it (you're using that when you pass a module ID to the loadmodule plugin). Plugins are designed to insert things into articles, modules are designed to live elsewhere on the page.

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do properly, I think you're looking to write a plugin, not a module. The good news is that they're a lot simpler to write, as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, you're right. A plugin does in fact sound more suitable for this. Do you maybe know a good tutorial for plugin development?

Comment: There's about three paragraphs in the middle of https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla that are worth reading and give you an overview of it (don't let the complex XML file scare you, it was a bad choice for that article). https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events is the list of events that can trigger a plugin. Beyond that, go to your joomla installation and look in the folder plugins/content for some examples of working plugins to help guide you. And https://github.com/Paladin/pig_buttoneer is a simple plugin that will probably give you a little help along the way, as well.